# loadable levels with code in addition to assets in xamarin

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

I am a newbie to Xamarin, and I have searched SO and Google for this but I have not found the right query to get my answer.  In flex, I can create a "module" and it can have assets, code, etc, and in that module I can implement a class based on an interface in the main app, and load it after the main app is loaded.

In a game that I have written I load my levels this way.  It works great because the core app is totally independent and rarely requires updates.

Basically imagine that the main app has an IGameEngine interface for any interaction with it, and each level that is loaded from the cloud and cached locally (like Angry Birds Seasons does with levels), will have an implementation of that IGameEngine which may or may not be the same or different from other levels, depending on the features needed in that level.

I will be using xamarin because I am comfortable with C# and have a need to target all platforms, and thus need to minimize the code to do so.  I will most likely also be using CocosSharp as it seems to be an active community.

In Xamarin can I do something similar?  How?  When I search for Xamarin "modules", I get a million results for how to include a module in the compiler, obviously I'm searching for the wrong keywords.

Sorry for a question that an experienced user could probably locate in 5 seconds on Google, but I don't know where to start.  I appreciate any and all help from the community!

Comment: If you are referring module as a library that can be used in all platforms, you are looking  for the PCL - Portable Class Library or Shared Project

Comment: Thank you @guilherme-torres-castro , but no.  I'm looking for the equivalent of a flex module.  Runable code packaged as an external file that can be loaded and instantiated on demand.  My understanding is that a PCL would be my base app, with various UI projects utilizing it for each platform.  But that app will need to load binary assets and specific logic for each level.  Therefore I must load COMPLIED CODE which matches some interface no?  I can only assume there must be a way to do this.

Comment: check out how Angry Birds Seasons loads their levels.  I would like to do the same.  I know that I can load a file with assets easily enough.  But in my case, I need to also have logic for each level, or I risk having to push a new full app update every time  release a new level with a previously unimplemented feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of on-demand loading a .Net-based assembly, that will not work on platforms that are not running the full Mono stack (including JIT).

i.e. MonoTouch/Xam.iOS (and Xam.Mac store applications) would not allow you to dynamically load an CIL based assembly on the fly as that is a volition of Apple's policy and will not pass their application audit and thus there is no JIT'ing allowed. All code (CIL assemblies) must be natively compiled (AOT'd) and pre-packaged in your IPA. Of course you can download level metadata and media content dynamically.

Now on a platform like Android where native code OR Jit'ed code (i.e. Java) is  allowed, Xamarin provides the full Mono stack and you can dynamically load a new assembly into your process (across the wire downloaded or locally from flash) and it will be Jit'd on the fly and executed.

Comment: Very helpful, Robert.  Thank you very much.  ...

so i could do something like this:
var pluginAssets = Assets.List(pluginPath);
foreach (var pluginAsset in pluginAssets)
{
    var file = Assets.Open(pluginPath + Java.IO.File.Separator + pluginAsset);

    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        file.CopyTo(memStream);

        //do something fun.
        var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(memStream.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Loaded: {0}", assembly.FullName));
    }

}

Comment: but not on ios.  do you know if windows phone/win10 have similar restrictions?

Comment: No on the WinPhone, if it is not pre-packaged in your XAP, you can not load it. A lot of this of course concerns security so no-one can load any non-audited/rogue code into a running process. 'Loading' existing assemblies in a IPA/XAP return non-null but they really are already loaded...

Comment: FYI: You are not alone in your question, lots of devs have questions on this. search Xamarin forums you will find a number of threads related to this, some nicely detailed from the Xam devs themselves. Just search for "loading assembly" or such